# Posting to orion gets me to "Attribute must be a JSON object"

Tags: fiware-orion

I am sending this to Orion:

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://xx.xx.xx.xx:1026/ngsi-ld/v1/entities/' \
--header 'link: <https://smartdatamodels.org/context.jsonld>; rel="http://www.w3.org/ns/json-ld#context"; type="application/ld+json"' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
    "id": "urn:ngsi-ld:Device:01",
    "type": "Device",
    "description": "L9A",
    "category": {
        "value": ["sensor"]
    },
    "serialNumber": {
        "value": "38479144"
    },
    "controlledProperty": {
        "value": ["Water Supply"]
    },
    "owner": {
        "value": ["Me"]
    },
    "location": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [20.200416, 30.261837]
    }
}'
```

and I get this:

Error 400: Bad Request

```
{
    "type": "https://uri.etsi.org/ngsi-ld/errors/BadRequestData",
    "title": "Attribute must be a JSON object",
    "detail": "description"
}
```

I validated by json object and it passes. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look a little closer at your error message, especially:

```
detail": "description"
```

That's the name of the attribute that is not a JSON object:

```
"description": "L9A"
```

If you change it to:

```
"description": {
  "type": "Property",
  "value": "L9A"
}
```

that part should be OK.

But, the `type` member seems to be missing for all your attributes.
you'll need to add `"type": "Property"` to all of them, except "location" that's a `GeoProperty`:

```
"location": {
  "type": "GeoProperty",
  "value": {
    "type": "Point",
    "coordinates": [20.200416, 30.261837]
  }
}
```

Perhaps spend some time reading the NGSI-LD specification?
https://www.etsi.org/deliver/etsi_gs/CIM/001_099/009/01.04.02_60/gs_CIM009v010402p.pdf

Comment: Thanks it worked like a charm!! you are right about the NGSI-LD spec. This is a super minor sub-project thing regarding to my main flow of work and I didn't have enough time to look into the specs. But I guess I will have to.